# set different values for drop down list if check box checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, php

i have a drop down list like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<select name="test">
<option>very good</option>
<option>nice</option>
<option>not bad</option>
<option>bad</option>
</select>
```

i want if check box checked show me 'not bad' and 'bad' values or if check box unchecked show 'nice' and 'very nice' values. in other hand, change values of drop down list by changing check box value. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It's definitely *possible*. It would be great if you tried solving it before anyone gives you the answer though. Some things to search: onchange event, get element by name, set innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your HTML page like so, having `very good` and `nice` options as defaults for unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<select name="test" id="selectMenu">
    <option>very good</option>
    <option>nice</option>
</select>
```

I've assigned the select menu with the id of `selectMenu`.

Here I used jQuery. I stored references to the `checkbox` and the `select menu`, and also created default "templates" to change the innerHtml when it is either unchecked or checked. For `checkedContent`, I created it with your desired options, and for `uncheckedContent` I simply set it as the default innerHtml, which is the `very good` and nice `options`.

```
//store dom references in vars
var $checkbox = $("#checkbox");
var $selectMenu = $("#selectMenu");

var checkedContent = "<option>not bad</option><option>bad</option>";
var uncheckedContent = $selectMenu.html();

$checkbox.on("click", function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.is(":checked:not")){
      $selectMenu.html(checkedContent);
    } else {
     $selectMenu.html(uncheckedContent);
    }
});
```

Take a look at the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h4nk5k9x/).

Comment: its true but not working in my console. should i put jquery codes in script tag?

Comment: i did not used jquery before. please put required library and other things